# Limpar campo tipo pesquisa

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

estou com um problema que não consigo resolver, estou realizando a construção de um sistema de inventario para biblioteca, e estou utilizando uma leitora para ler os códigos de barras dos livros,  porém depois que utilizo a leitora para pegar o código e pesquisar no banco, o campo não e limpo, porém quando adiciono o código
        `$(document).keypress(function(e) { if(e.which == 13) $('#btn-search').click(); document.getElementById('input-search').value=''; });`
O campo e limpo, porém como a leitora da um enter depois de ler, o parametro de pesquisa vai em branco e ai o sistema faz uma consulta no banco com parâmetro vazio, segue o código.

Busca.php
`

search($search)) 

   Livro não registrado na base de dados...



   Dados da busca:

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
           <th>Titulo</th>
           <th>Codigo de Barras</th>
           <th>Biblioteca</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <?php foreach($user->search($search) as $row): ?>
        <tr>
           <td><?php echo $row->tituloexemplar; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row->codigobarra;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row->nomebiblioteca; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

`
pesquisa.php
`
   

   
      Inventário 
      
      
      
   
   
      
         
            
               
                  
                  
                  Pesquisar

```
  <!-- script -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/usuarios.js"></script>
  <script>
     $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) $('#btn-search').click();
        document.getElementById('input-search').value='';
  });
  </script>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<body>
<input id="input-search" placeholder="informe o código"/> <br/> <br/> <input id="input-display"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#input-search').keypress(function (e) {
        
        let value_search;
        

        // se precionar enter numerico ou alfanumerico  e input não for vázio
        // (leitores emulam "Ender" do teclado)
        if (e.key == 'Enter' && !!$(this).val()) {
            
            // guardar valor do input
            value_search = $(this).val();
            
            // limpar input
            $(this).val('');
            
            //  agora o valor está separado do input que foi limpo para próxima consultar
            // aqui poderá ser trabalhado a lógia par o valor informado.
            $('#input-display').val(value_search)
            
        }
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Opa Lindomar, obrigado pela resposta, porém ainda cair no mesmo dilema, o campo input-search, depois de ler na leitora ele não limpa o campo, ai quando vou tentar ler outro livro, o campo continua preenchido, precisaria que cada vez que fosse feito um consulta no banco, o campo input-search fosse limpo, porém sem executar uma ação, até ler o próximo codigo.

Comment: troque       

  document.getElementById('input-search').value='';

por

 $('#input-search').val('')

Comment: Testou o código? Ele limpa o campo input-search apos a consulta, só precisa adaptar pra sua necessidade

Comment: Fiz o teste, só que quando faço o processo ele preenche o segundo input, e no primeiro ele busca todos os resultados do banco, talvez o problema seja meu javascript, porém não consegui identificar o que está de errado.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

   // Busca os dados no banco ao pressiona a tecla
   $("#btn-search").click(function () {
      var search = $("#input-display").val();
      buscar(search);
   });
   function buscar(valor)
   {
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'html',
         url: 'buscar.php',
         beforeSend: function () {
            $("#dados").html("Carregando...");
         },
         data: {valor: valor},
         success: function (result) {
            $("#dados").html(result);
         }
      });
   }
});

Comment: Lindomar, fiz uma alteração aqui no js e funcionou, cara muito obrigado.